# iFrame Display issue within webkit column

Tags: macos, css, google-chrome, iframe, webkit

iFrames only display properly in the first column.  I added some images to show how they display properly, while the iFrames do not.  The iframe flashes, then disappears.  Please advise!  I'm using Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 on Mac

I have a demo setup as follows:
styles:

```
.content {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1%;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1%;
    column-gap: 1%;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

.item iframe, .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fwkJtgVswgM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
    <div class="item"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fwkJtgVswgM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://twopointoakland.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/bluedemobutton.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmy96hop/1/

Comment: I can confirm that this is an issue on windows 7 & 8.1 in Chrome v.42